# How do I make a specific query in a PSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I need help with a project. Right now, I have a giant postgreSQL database (~6 million rows, 25 columns) and I need to figure out how to get the following information:

For one specific range for one attribute, "20<np<400":

- Find local minimum values in another variable, "itt"
- Record whole row of data for that local minimum
- Add extra column and add to this the next local maximum of itt

Edit: the attribute are as follows: The database has this schema: id | at | itt | engine_torque | ng | np | fuel_flow | engine_oil_pressure | engine_oil_temp | airspeed | altitude | total_air_temp | weight_on_wheels | p25_p3 | bypass | chip_counter | number_of_flight_counter | number_of_engine_run | run_id | ectm_file_id | aircraft_sn | engine_sn | gas_generator_sn | power_section_sn | tail_number

By 'local minima and maxima' i mean that within a certain range of np, i'm looking for the highest and lowest values of itt in close proximity with respect to time, or "at"

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: We'd need to see your schema, your indexes, and what "itt", "np", "exp" and so on mean. Also what is meant by "find local minimum values in another variable", SQL doesn't have variables. Some sample data and your expected result would help greatly.

Comment: Btw: 6 million rows isn't considered "giant" (not even "large" these days)

Comment: The database has this schema:    id    |           at           |  itt   | engine_torque |  ng   |   np    | fuel_flow | engine_oil_pressure | engine_oil_temp | airspeed | altitude | total_air_temp | weight_on_wheels |  p25_p3   | bypass | chip_counter | number_of_flight_counter | number_of_engine_run | run_id | ectm_file_id | aircraft_sn | engine_sn | gas_generator_sn | power_section_sn | tail_number

Comment: By 'local minima and maxima' i mean that within a certain range of np, i'm looking for the highest and lowest values of itt in close proximity with respect to time, or "at"